# Can Javascript be compiled and run instead of being interpreted?

Tags: javascript, optimization

I've read that a reason why Javascript is slow is because it is interpreted and not compiled. But in theory any language that can be interpreted can also be compiled right?? Then why not create a faster Javascript Engine that compiles the code. What part of the Javascript slowdown is caused by this factor?

Comment: Modern JS engines do that very thing.

Comment: JS is not slow, it's faster than a lot of other popular languages in fact...

Comment: To head off a flamewar here, JS itself is neither slow nor fast. Implementations have a lot of leeway to figure out how to optimize and implement different parts of the specification, including whether to compile or interpret.

Comment: Technically Javascript is slower than the languages that are pre-compiled, because Javascript is dynamically typed.

Answer (score 2):

Most modern implementations of interpreted languages use JIT compilation at the very least. The only thing precompiling would buy you would be compile time errors, not speed.

For instance, V8 compiles the javascript it gets in the background:
http://thenextweb.com/google/2014/02/13/google-speeds-chrome-compiling-javascript-background/

Comment: no, some languages are pure interpretation, like IE6's JScript engine for example... or bat files.

Comment: You're right, I had how interpreted languages were actually interpreted confused. They're translated into precompiled commands, but not directly compiled, a subtle but meaningful nuance. Edited my answer.

Comment: No but code optimization is better done with compilation right?? And that in turn makes it faster.. At least that's what they taught me in college..

Comment: Do you mean the optimization the compiler does to the code? That's still achieved with just in time compilation.